# Lagged features in time series feature engineering

Tags: time-series, missing-data, feature-engineering, data-imputation, lags

I understand the value of using lagged features in time series analyses, but conceptually I've still quite a bit to learn. When creating lagged features for modeling purposes, **should I remove the rows that contain the induced NA values**? I've come across a couple of articles (i.e., [AnalyticsVidhya](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/12/6-powerful-feature-engineering-techniques-time-series/) and [Machine Learning Mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/basic-feature-engineering-time-series-data-python/)) that suggest "discarding" the rows because there is not enough information to train a model. See the table below.

```
time   x   x-1   x-2   x-3
0     10   NA    NA    NA
1     12   10    NA    NA
2     14   12    10    NA
3     16   14    12    10
4     18   16    14    12
5     20   18    16    14
```

Secondly, what are the (statistical) rules, if any, around replacing the NA values with 0s? Conceptually, I'm unsure if imputing 0s also induces some kind of information to a model (e.g., `h2o.gbm()` treats NAs like categorical variables for splits so I would rather not make the model less interpretable than it already is even though it's relatively powerful at predicting). Is it even remotely practical to think of the NAs as 0s?

Note: I've run the `h2o.gbm()` algorithm on a data set that has a similar structure as the table above and the overall prediction **decreased** markedly for the model that used 0s in place of NAs. I tend to be more statistically conservative, so I *feel* much more comfortable using the model that removes the rows altogether but always open to suggestions!